# How to create variable feature with prosMirror

Tags: javascript, prose-mirror

I am trying to create variable feature. i cant understand how to do the schema feature.

**the outcome i want:**
view in the editor:

```html
<div>hello <span style="background:blue;" class="editor-variable" data-value="fullName">fullName</span></div>
<div>this is another row</div>
```

view on get html string:

```html
 <div>hello {{fullname}} </div>
 <div>this is another row</div>
```

```html
i want <span style="background:blue;" class="editor-variable" data-value="fullName">fullName</span>
to be translate to {{fullName}}
```